# How to correctly set the width and height of a FrameBuffer in libgdx?

Tags: opengl, libgdx, framebuffer, fbo

I am using a `FrameBuffer` to rasterize several `TextureRegions` in a single `TextureRegion`, to be drawn on an `Image`/`Actor` afterwards.

The constructor of a `FrameBuffer` is the following:

```
FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format format, int width, int height, boolean hasDepth)
```

I found that if I put `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()`/`getHeight()` as the width and height parameters in the constructor the image is drawn correctly, but if I put something else (like the rasterized texture size) the texture is way smaller and is pixelated if I increase the size. Have I missed something ?

```
TextureRegion initialTexture = getTexture();
// And other textures, which are not shown here for better readability

FrameBuffer frameBuffer = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, (int)initialTexture.getRegionWidth(), (int)initialTexture.getRegionHeight(), false);
Batch batch = new SpriteBatch();

// Adding these lines did the trick
Camera camera = new OrthographicCamera(frameBuffer.getWidth(), frameBuffer.getHeight());
camera.position.set(frameBuffer.getWidth() / 2, frameBuffer.getHeight() / 2, 0);
camera.update();
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

frameBuffer.begin();
batch.enableBlending();

Gdx.gl.glBlendFuncSeparate(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

batch.begin();

batch.setColor(TAPColor.TAP_WHITE);
batch.draw(initialTexture, 0, 0);
// Also draw other textures

batch.end();
frameBuffer.end();

TextureRegion finalTexture = new TextureRegion(frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture());

Image image = new Image(finalTexture);
image.setSize(finalTexture.getRegionWidth(), finalTexture.getRegionHeight());
image.setPosition(0, 0);
addActor(image);
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to setup a camera and call `batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);`

Comment: It doesn't seem to change anything by setting the projection matrix on the batch (I updated the code)

Comment: You can't use the same camera for your fbo as you use for your screen. Create a separate camera (or Viewport if you prefer) and make sure to set it's size according to the fbo (e.g. `cam.viewportWidth = fbo.getWidth(); cam.viewportHeight = fbo.getHeight();` or `viewport.update(fbo.getWidth(), fbo.getHeight());`). Although that assumes a pixel perfect projection.

Comment: Ok good to know. I changed to Camera camera = new OrthographicCamera(fbo.getWidth(), fbo.getHeight()); and set the position to camera.position.set(fbo.getWidth() / 2, fbo.getHeight() / 2, 0); and it works perfectly now. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems too, one thing that made it simple was:

```
  Matrix4 projection = new Matrix4();
  projection.setToOrtho2D(0, 0, 32, 48);
  batch.setProjectionMatrix(projection);
```